# me da el error: "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

Hasta el final en la parte de int busqueda en el metodo if me da el error "cannot find symbol"

cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

```
public class AdmonPersonal {
   private Personal p[];
   private int cont;
   
   public AdmonPersonal() {
      p = new Personal[99];
      cont = 0;
   }
   
   public boolean hayEspacio() {
      if (cont < p.length) {
         return true;
        } 
        return false;
      }
      
      public boolean validarId(int id) {
         if (id >= 1 && id <=100) {
             return true;
             }
             return false;
             }
             
      public int busqueda(int id) {
         int celda = -1;
         for (int x=0; x<<cont; x++) {
            if (id == p[x].getId()) {// aqui da el cannot find symbol
               celda = x;
               break;
             }
           }
           return celda;
          }
         }
```

Comment: El operador `<<` es para desplazar bits a la izquierda, dentro de un bucle for no sirve para nada, supongo que querras indicar menor que `<` o menor igual `<=`. Y el segundo for te sobra completamente ya que es identico al primero

Comment: ya no me aparecio el primer error, el segundo me equivoque y lo repeti, el verdadero error  de "cannot find symbol" aparece en el "if"

Comment: antes de responder una pregunta deberían aclarar todos los detalles.